# http.get is not a function when running unit test in angular with karma and jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm doing an unit of an angular app. When launching the app normally( ng serve) there is no probelem with service. But when running the units test , I get this problem.

[error on the cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGI4v.png)

Someone , help please.

Comment: in your `facture-list.component.spec.ts` you need to mock the `HttpClient` service. to so by providing a mock in the TestBed's providers array. ps: you should abstract the http call in a service instead of using `HttpClient` directly in your component.

Comment: i think i did this this trick before but it didn't resolve the problem